# URDF model moving away whenever launched in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Whenever i try to load my URDF (with Gazebo sensor Pluigns), the model spawn's successfully but it moves away weirdly like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMoaO2srxqI&feature=youtu.be) video

This is my urdf and i have also attached my [launch file](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15001075998039631.launch)

I googled but unable to figure out what mistake i did, hope some one clears it ...! :)

Thank your for your response in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot
  name="hdf_model">
  <link name="footprint" />

  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="footprint"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
  </joint>   

  <link
    name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0710712962197142 -0.000137753873757876 -0.0472356807568853"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.8968201286225" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0435515415861913"
        ixy="-7.54353183930224E-05"
        ixz="-0.0120679749993695"
        iyy="0.0775488218939522"
        iyz="3.02473586563858E-05"
        izz="0.105083705856808" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://hdf_model/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://hdf_model/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>              

  <link
    name="front_left_wheel_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 -6.3295189589585E-07 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.482131555796721" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000893944886202995"
        ixy="-4.51240238343766E-20"
        ixz="1.17525821431534E-20"
        iyy="0.00168163508591572"
        iyz="-3.96864618172625E-21"
        izz="0.000893944886202995" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://hdf_model/meshes/front_left_wheel_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.294117647058824 0.294117647058824 0.294117647058824 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://hdf_model/meshes/front_left_wheel_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint
    name="front_left_wheel_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.0774999999999994 0.1925 -0.0930000000000001"
      rpy="1.29699056065384E-16 0.000304917468774119 3.60306029014719E-15" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="front_left_wheel_link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 -1 0" />
  </joint>

  <link
    name="front_right_wheel_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 -6.3295189589585E-07 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.482131555796721" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000893944886202993"
        ixy="-2.15673142206335E-20"
        ixz="-1.62630325872826E-19"
        iyy="0.00168163508591572"
        iyz="1.16692499357991E-20"
        izz="0.000893944886202994" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://hdf_model/meshes/front_right_wheel_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.294117647058824 0.294117647058824 0.294117647058824 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://hdf_model/meshes/front_right_wheel_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint
    name="front_right_wheel_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.0774999999999989 -0.192500000000001 -0.0930000000000001"
      rpy="1.54507720819671E-16 -0.580624336864947 3.51749903859331E-15" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="front_right_wheel_link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 -1 0" />
  </joint>

  <link
    name="laser_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-8.54230302427539E-05 6.72214995819098E-05 0.0299775216686896"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.149621221992963" />
      <inertia
        ixx="8.91590299505418E-05"
        ixy="8.67289898114126E-08"
        ixz="4.3986338046771E-08"
        iyy="8.93716564388956E-05"
        iyz="-2.34056549904993E-07"
        izz="5.2029602781235E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://hdf_model/meshes/laser_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://hdf_model/meshes/laser_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint
    name="laser_joint"
    type="fixed">
    <origin
      xyz="0.220650000000521 0 0"
      rpy="2.01948391736579E-28 2.46519014539409E-32 5.03235953499442E-12" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="laser_link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>


  <link
    name="ultrasonic_link_right_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.13 0.26 0.005"
        rpy="0 0 2.0944" />
      <mass
        value="0.149621221992963" />
      <inertia
        ixx="8.91590299505418E-05"
        ixy="8.67289898114126E-08"
        ixz="4.3986338046771E-08"
        iyy="8.93716564388956E-05"
        iyz="-2.34056549904993E-07"
        izz="5.2029602781235E-05" />
    </inertial> 
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.13 0.26 0.005"
        rpy="0 0 2.0944" />
      <geometry>
         <box size="0.001 0.045 0.02"/>
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 0.423529 0.0392154 1.0" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.01 -0.01 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
         <box size="0.045 0.02 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint
    name="ultrasonic_joint_right_1"
    type="fixed">
    <origin
        xyz="-0.13 0.26 0.005"
        rpy="0 0 2.0944" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="ultrasonic_link_right_1" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>  
        
  <gazebo reference="footprint">
     <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
     <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo> 

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
     <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
     <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="front_left_wheel_link">
            <mu1 value="1.0"/>
        <mu2 value="1.0"/>
        <kp  value="10000000.0" />
        <kd  value="1.0" />
            <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
        <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="front_right_wheel_link">
            <mu1 value="1.0"/>
        <mu2 value="1.0"/>
        <kp  value="10000000.0" />
        <kd  value="1.0" />
            <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
        <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="ultrasonic_link_right_1">  
      <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
      <sensor type="ray" name="ultrasonic_sensor">
        <always_on>true</always_on>
        <update_rate>10</update_rate>  <!-- not correct value -->                                  
        <pose>-0.13 0.26 0.005 0 0 2.0944</pose>        
        <visualize>true</visualize>
        <ray>
          <scan>
            <horizontal>
              <samples>100</samples>
              <resolution>1</resolution>
              <min_angle>-0.130899694</min_angle>
              <max_angle>00.130899694</max_angle>
            </horizontal>
            <vertical>
              <samples>100</samples>
              <resolution>1</resolution>
              <min_angle>-0.130899694</min_angle>
              <max_angle>00.130899694</max_angle>
            </vertical>
          </scan>
          <range>
            <min>0.02</min>
            <max>4.00</max>
            <resolution>0.01</resolution>
          </range>
        </ray>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_ultrasonic_controller" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_sonar.so">
     <gaussianNoise>0.05</gaussianNoise>
          <topicName>range/distance</topicName>
          <frameId>ultrasonic_link_right_1</frameId>
        </plugin>
      </sensor>
   </gazebo> 

  <gazebo reference="laser_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
        <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
        <sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
          <visualize>true</visualize>
          <update_rate>40</update_rate>
          <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>720</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
            <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.10</min>
          <max>100.0</max>
          <resolution>0.001</resolution>
        </range>
                <noise>
                  <type>gaussian</type>
                 <!-- Noise parameters based on published spec for Hokuyo laser
                  achieving "+-30mm" accuracy at range < 10m.  A mean of 0.0m and
                  stddev of 0.01m will put 99.7% of samples within 0.03m of the true
                  reading. -->
                  <mean>0.0</mean>
                  <stddev>0.01</stddev>
                </noise>
          </ray>
          <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
        <gaussianNoise>0.000</gaussianNoise>
        <topicName>/scan</topicName>
        <frameName>hokuyo_link</frameName>
          </plugin>
       </sensor>
  </gazebo>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16764/urdf-model-moving-away-whenever-launched-in-gazebo/) by [ajay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3587/ajay/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Panda1638](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3537/panda1638/) on 2017-07-19**:
I had problems with a misbehaving robot arm shortly. It was shaking. It stoped after lowering the mass. Try to change your parameters in your URDF. Also isolating the Problem by removing parts could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Based on your video, it looks like there is no ground plane. This would cause the model to fall directly down.

Take a look at your `hdf.world` file.  You can add a ground plane in that file using the following:

```
<include>
  <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2017-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ajay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3587/ajay/) on 2017-07-19**:
Yeah, i didn't include the ground plane properly, problem got resolved, thank you...!